# HTTP Piping or passthru

Tags: http, web, websocket

I have a need to implement a solution where I need a web client to connect to a web server and receive frequent updates of information as they happen.  The updates are actually driven from a separate device which posts data to a web server (may be different).  What I am unclear on is how do I take data updates coming in on one http connection (from the device) and pass the data thru to another http connection (the client).

device in the field -> web server -> client application

Answer (score 1):

HTTP connections from the client are not persistent by default, ie the client will need to implement some mechanism to get the latest information. The mentioned mechanism can go from something extremely simple as the client hitting F5 on the browser, to something more elaborated as the use of web sockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). A middle ground solution will be giving the client the ability to update itself (querying the server using javascript, for instance)

So, to put it in an example:

Your "device" will send a request to your server, let's say a POST or GET request, that will trigger an "action" in the server. Now, the server can notify the client (via websockets) or the client can query the server every X seconds (using ajax and a javascript timer, for instance)